# Bottom rough edge

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

I am trying to get rid of the bottom rough edge of my printed jobs. It is on everything I print. I have adjusted my Initial layer settings but no change. I have the Ender 3 and using the provided Creality Slicer.

Picture showing the problem:

[image]

Comment: I have also adjusted various bed temps.  As well as 1st layer settings.

Comment: Unless you update the question with the bed temperatures and settings you changed it is guesswork for us. Please update the question by [edit]. This problem looks exactly like in [this question](/q/8022)! I'm in favor for closing it a a duplicate.